# JAXB, how to generate classes for a schema with duplicated attribute for element

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a schema, namely [a schema for metalink file](http://www.metalinker.org/schema/3.0/metalink.xsd). For which I want ot generate classes using Maven maven-jaxb2-plugin.

This schema allows entering version as either attribute or element, so it has a duplicated property. How can I generate a Java class for such schema (is it even possible) using Jaxb and without renaming attribute nor element. So basically I would like this duplicated property mapped to some kind of complex type with internal indication of whether it was attribute or element. At least such solution would look to me as the closest representation of XML.

Can something like this be achieved? If yes, then how?

Underneath, said problematic xsd fragment.

```
<xs:complexType name="metalinkType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="identity" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="license" type="licenseType"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="publisher" type="publisherType"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="releasedate" type="RFC822DateTime"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tags" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="version" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="files" type="filesType"/>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" default="3.0"/>
    <xs:attribute name="origin" type="xs:anyURI"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" default="static">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="dynamic"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="static"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="pubdate" type="RFC822DateTime"/>
    <xs:attribute name="refreshdate" type="RFC822DateTime"/>
    <xs:attribute name="generator" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

**EDIT**:

And for such schema I would like to have generated by Jaxb a Java model, like:

```
public class Metalink {
    private PropertyType<String> version;
    ...
}

public class PropertyType<T> {
    private T val;
    private boolean isAttribute;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this or is the only solution to have two different properties in Java model?

Comment: You can use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to create an structure as you want, but you will always will end with a Jaxb Java model based on two attributes.... I would suggest to take my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can be done through [JAXB Binding Customization](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/6n5sg7bkr/index.html).

This is a small XSD that I made to meet your problem (name collision between an attribute and element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://hello"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:tns="http://hello"
>
    <xs:element name="metalink" type="tns:metalinkType" />
    <xs:complexType name="metalinkType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

When executing the JAXB Generation from **eclipse**, I get an error like:

```
[ERROR] Property "Version" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict
```

But, when I modified the XSD with some customization tags, the problem goes away:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://hello"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:tns="http://hello"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" <!-- ADDED -->
    jaxb:version="1.0" <!-- ADDED -->
>
    <xs:element name="metalink" type="tns:metalinkType" />
    <xs:complexType name="metalinkType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required" >
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property name="version2"/> <!-- ADDED! -->
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Avoiding the collision problem and allowing to generated the associated classes.

**NOTE:** The presented example assumes that you want (and you can) to modify the problematic XSD with inline customizations... according to the documentation, you can also define customizations at external files (you need to check and try this).

[this](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2) is another link of interest...

Hope this help!

** Update ** : Example to achieve the Java model that you want.. the example assumes that you followed the steps described just before... you will end with a class like this:

```
// xml annotations
public class MetalinkType {
     ...
    @XmlElement(name = "version)
    private String version;
    ...
    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    private String version2;
    ...
    public void setVersion(String version, boolean asElem) {
        If (asElem) {
            this.version = version;
        } else {
            this.version2 = version;
        }
    }
    // individual setter as setVersion and setVersion2 are not exposed
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution would make the schema compile, but it is not what I was looking (hoping) for. What I try to achieve is have only one property `version` in Java model, just somehow marked with info if it is an xml element or attribute. That's why the main question was is it possible.

Comment: If you could do that, how do you expect to set such mark? Through some setter method??

Comment: If through a setter method, my solution works, I'll give you an example...